# Construct a Netflix Affiliate URL to a search result page?

Tags: netflix

I have a Netflix Affiliate account, but I don't want to direct users to the homepage for them to create an account, I want to direct them to a search result page. The reason for this is that on our site we have lots of titles but they can't be reliably linked to a single Netflix result programmatically, so we would prefer if we could direct users to a search page, and if the user signs up, get the revenue. Is this possible? I find the whole Netflix-Affiliate-but-Google-Affiliate scheme a bit daunting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question once again. I found the answer [here](http://developer.netflix.com/docs/Affiliate_Program) (a bit hidden that link). For anyone wondering about the same problem, here's a quote from that page:

> Deep linking (linking to pages other than the main Netflix login page) is a little more complicated - the structure is:
>
> [http://clickserve.cc-dt.com/link/tplclick?lid=41000000030242852&pubid=00000000000000000&redirect=[Endcoded](http://clickserve.cc-dt.com/link/tplclick?lid=41000000030242852&pubid=00000000000000000&redirect=%5BEndcoded) Deep linking URL]

That works pretty good.

Comment: +1 Take note to properly submit your GAN (Google Affiliate Network) ID.

Answer (score 0):

I would be wary of using Felix's example above before confirming your account details with the Netflix API team. I think you need to first submit your Google ID (GAN) along with your API key so that they will credit leads generated with the above structure.

Read the details on http://developer.netflix.com/docs/Affiliate_Program

Answer (score 0):

Even worse, if you use http://www.netflix.com/Search?v1=Jaws it returns a search result appropriately for "Jaws" if you're not logged into Netflix, but if you happen to already be logged in to your Netflix account it takes you to the Netflix homepage instead. This is with the affiliate linkage element out of the equation entirely, so there are multiple issues at stake.

I'm looking for the solution too, and have had no response from Netflix or the Google Affiliate Network.